# Why does the default setting for `requestPathInvalidCharacters` exclude otherwise-allowed characters?

Tags: asp.net, url, uri, standards

In ASP.NET, the `httpRuntime/@requestPathInvalidCharacters` attribute defaults to `<,>,*,%,&,:,\`. These characters, as I understand, are disallowed in the path portion of a URL (based on the default setting of this attribute), but some of them should be allowed. Out of that list, I struggle to understand why `*,&,:` are disallowed by default. E.g., the following URLs are *valid* but would be rejected by default by ASP.NET:

*To get a unique person by email:* http://myservice.com/People/Email=jim@smith.net

*To get a unique locality within a state:* http://myservice.com/States/VA/Localities/FIPS=001

I could also swap out the `=` for `:` to make ASP.NET reject the URL by default. But these characters/URLs are valid and should/do work fine.

So, does anyone have any insight into why these disallowed characters were chosen?

(Related post/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13500078/374198)

Comment: +1 Had to find out myself :) Here's the [best explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3342765/304683) I've found so far (at least for colon `:`). Haven't tried this - what about seeing if it works as query string (after `?`) instead of "virtual path" (as mentioned)?

Comment: @EdSF I'll take a look at the link, thanks. I want to do some of this stuff in the path in cases where the path identifies a unique entity, rather than querying multiple entities (which as you mentioned should be done in the query string). My examples are bad, admittedly. Will update them.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it helps to uncover one use case, at least.