# Good idea to use colons in url?

Tags: .htaccess, url

I'm building a small system, which has nice htaccess rewritten urls. Now I'm wondering if it's a good idea to use colons for it. Here's an example:

```
domain.tld/section:Foo/page:12
```

It's a lot more stable than something like this, as it describes every string:

```
domain.tld/section/Foo/12
```

The only problem is, will all browsers support it right? I know Wikipedia uses them :)

Matti Laine

Comment: Yes, all browsers support it. It's not as good as it looks like for SEO, for instance .. if that has any relevance to you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's highly unrecommended.
It's not standards-compliant, and can cause some trouble.

See: [Is a colon safe for friendly-URL use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053132/is-a-colon-safe-for-friendly-url-use)

Comment: That question is about making sure that "no colon [...] will be url-encoded by browsers". That doesn't mean they are not safe and, if fact, not the same question *at all*.

Comment: You are right Andrew, but I wanted to point out that a decision to support colons might introduce other [unexpected] problems, not necessarily on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Yes browsers will be fine with it. However, I don't see why it's more "stable" than the usual `/Foo/12`. The whole point of url-rewriting is that you don't expose what the parameter names are (i.e. `?section=Foo&page=12`). If you're just putting parameter names back in then what was the point?

Answer (score 0):

The colon is fine browsers; will URL encode any characters that would cause problems. The later form (using slashes) is more inline with the [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) architecture which will probably be more recognizable/standard if you plan on offering something like a webservice in the future.