# How to encode/decode url in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am sending a link to my user's email to activate his account by click that link.
example link: 
http://test.com/welcome/make_active_user/($user_id)

then I encode `$user_id` in my controller, after that my link looks like the following one

http://test.com/welcome/make_active_user/17elQOjxrOXDsZdDZVFY7JFrB0TJFojdS+5OTpiIq/XXIaVrDfVWQ7xgOXXqGsURIFe/Udvm/XHrNWtbZXFA2g==

upto this everything is fine. Now i want to decode the `$user_id`,
but "`/`" symbol create problem. codeigniter took only those characters before the "`/`" symbol. How can i get a output of encoded user_id without "`/`"

I use "`$this->encrypt->encode($user_id,$key);`" in my controller

Please help

Comment: Check this link you will find what you want : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268873/codeignitor-urlencode-decode

Comment: not working, only took as a id before / symbol from the url

Comment: you should use some encode method that does not produce any `/` `#` `&`  and some others character like ending with `==`. I think you used base64 which will not work.I used bin2hex and hex2bin

Answer (score 6):

Just pass your encoded `$user_id` to the php function `urlencode()` before sending in a link like this:

```
$user_id_link = urlencode($user_id);
```

And decode the string you get back from the link with `url decode()` like this:

```
$user_id = urldecode($user_id_link);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to modify the encrypt class to encode url safe strings.

```
class MY_Encrypt extends CI_Encrypt
{

    function encode($string, $key="", $url_safe=true)
    {
        $ret = parent::encode($string, $key);

        if ($url_safe)
        {
            $ret = strtr(
                    $ret,
                    array(
                        '+' => '.',
                        '=' => '-',
                        '/' => '~'
                    )
                );
        }

        return $ret;
    }


    function decode($string, $key="")
    {
        $string = strtr(
                $string,
                array(
                    '.' => '+',
                    '-' => '=',
                    '~' => '/'
                )
            );

        return parent::decode($string, $key);
    }
}
```

Then you can create a `$url_safe` link

Grab the encryption key from your config

```
$key = $this->config->item('encryption_key');
```

Create a url safe string by passing true as the third parameter

```
$encoded_url_safe_string = urlencode($this->encrypt->encode('secret', $key, true));
```

You will need to use `rawurldecode` to decode the string

```
$decoded_url_safe_string = rawurldecode($encoded_url_safe_string, $key);
```

Comment: Isn't your solution doing the same thing 2 times? Your modified MY_Encrypt class is de-/encoding the characters and the php functions urlencode() and url decode() are doing it again.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem in the past, codeigniter `encrypt->encode()`has disallowed chars for URL but i did the following to solve the problem

1. first `encode()` your `$user_id`
2. simply replace the disallowed chars from the encrypted string with allowed one.
3. now before decoding replace those chars back to original one
4. `decode()` your `$user_id`

here is the code:

```
$this->encrypt->encode($user_id,$key);
$user_id = strtr($user_id,array('+' => '.', '=' => '-', '/' => '~'));
//your email body (link the user id here)
```

now time for decoding

```
$user_id = strtr($user_id,array('.' => '+', '-' => '=', '~' => '/'));
$this->encrypt->decode($user_id,$key);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem isn't with the '/', probably it's with '=' symbol.

To code and decode a url in CodeIgniter you can use any of this php native functions: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.url.php

But to avoid problems when decode the encoded url in CodeIgniter, you can add the special character that you require to use in each case (like '=' in your case) to $config['permitted_uri_chars'] in file application/config/config.php

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

`$query = urldecode($query);`

`$query = urlencode($query);`

Comment: Please clean up the duplicate code and add a short explanation of what your code does. Clean and clear answers are the best answers