# Dynamic OpenGraph Object URL not working

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-graph-api, parameters, request

I am trying to post an open graph activity. Actually it's working with a static .html file. But if i point to a url with url params i get an error. The sourcecode on both pages is 100% the same, trust me.

```
# Dynamic call
/me/somesandbox:drive?car=http://www.domain.com/object/?og:type=somesandbox:car&og:title=Some%20car

# Static call
/me/somesandbox:drive?car=http://www.domain.com/static_car.html
```

**Error:**
*"Object at URL 'http://www.domain.com/object/?og:type' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:type' of type 'string' was not provided."*

**If you look at the error, you ll see, that Facebook didnt get the whole url. The params are missing, right. Please help!**

Comment: try surrounding the tag *values* with escaped quotation marks.

Comment: Nope, this is a url. Works in the browser and the Facbebook URL Linter

Comment: but clearly you are not using it in the browser or linter.  Have you considered that the language you are coding in might have escaping considerations?

Comment: Sry, the code is not a language. Just an example.

Comment: what language are you using?  Would help to add it in the tags...

Comment: Seeing the code used to generate the OG tags and having the actual URL (so we can Lint it in the debugger) would be very helpful!

Comment: @fabian I am with the same issue. In your view how did you decode the url? thanks

Comment: It's customary on SO to flag a response as accepted, rather than just sticking the answer in your own question.

Answer (score 4):

The Open Graph object url you are trying to use is this?

```
http://www.domain.com/object/?og:type=somesandbox:car&og:title=Some%20car
```

My guess is, since Facebook is already parsing `:` colon characters for the [action names](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/) (i.e. `graph.facebook.com/me/recipebox:cook?recipe=`), they might not be safe to use as your own parameters.

Also, there might be some confusion: so far as I know, Open Graph properties of objects are not passed in URLs like this `og:title=Some%20car`. They are actually uncoded in the page the URL points to, via the [open graph meta tags](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/): `<meta property="og:title" content="Some car" />`. So if you trying to set the Object properties with the URL, it won't work.

**Don't forget to use the [Lint Debug Tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to test out your Open Graph Object URLs!**

You probably do know this, though, and are just using the URL's GET parameters to set the `meta` tags. Something like this?

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<? echo $_GET['og:title'] ?>" />
```

If this is the case, just try it without the `:` colons. There is [some debate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053132/is-a-colon-safe-for-friendly-url-use) about whether they are safe in URLs anyway, but if Facebook is also parsing them it'll be safest to just leave them out, like this:

```
// http://www.domain.com/object/?ogtype=somesandbox:car&ogtitle=Some%20car
<meta property="og:type" content="<? echo $_GET['ogtype'] ?>" />
<meta property="og:title" content="<? echo $_GET['ogtitle'] ?>" />
```

I have not tested this, just giving some suggestions to try. Good luck!

Comment: Let me try to to this without the :

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has this nice tool to find out what the facebook see: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug just put the url, and watch the debug.

Don't forget, these meta tags have to be placed in  section.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. 
@thaddeusmt: Was already on the right track.

Which it super important - of course it is - you have to encodeURIComponent(yoururl?with=vars)

**Solved**

If you pass your url like this:

> /me/somesandbox:drive?car=http://www.domain.com/object/?og:type=somesandbox:car&og:title=Some%20car

Make sure to encode the object-url. E.g. with Javascript

```
encodeURIComponent(http://www.domain.com/object/?og:type=somesandbox:car&og:title=Some%20car)
```