# Qt QUrl: doesn't url-encode colon

Tags: c++, qt

I have URL: `https://example.com/hello?param=first:last`. I expect that it should be percent-encoded as `https://example.com/hello?param=first%3Alast`. But Qt leaves it as-is. My code:

```
QUrl url("https://example.com/hello?param=first:last");
printf("Encoded: %s\n", url.toEncoded().constData());
```

How should I encode colon? Manually format parameter with `QString::toPercentEncoding`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must replace colons because of security issues.

More information: http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

You can use percent encoding (":" -> "%3A") for colons, see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qurl.html#fromPercentEncoding and http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qurl.html#toPercentEncoding.

Comment: What are these security reasons?

Answer (score 0):

There has been some discussion regarding colon safety in URLs.  It sounds like it comes down to the RFC adherence which I'm not versed in.

[Is a colon safe for friendly-URL use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053132/is-a-colon-safe-for-friendly-url-use)

Looks like you may have to replace any ":" characters (after https:) yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think QUrl::toPercentEncoding() is your best bet. It encodes all standard characters by default, and you can manually specify your own list of additional characters to encode:

Reference URL:
http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qurl.html#toPercentEncoding

Comment: Unfortunately it will encode everything. Event colons in http: `http://hello.com` will be `http%3A%2F%2Fhello.com`. That not i want. I mentioned this method as manually encoding parameters.

Answer (score -1):

Pretty sure you want `QUrl::setEncodedURL` and `QUrl::toEncoded`

http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/platform-api-reference/xml/daily-docs/libqt4/qurl.html

Which version of Qt are you using?

IIRC Qt 3 used `QUrl:encode`

Comment: `QUrl::setEncodedUrl` excepts already percent-encoded string in the input. But I have raw string.