# Action redirect is not working with list attribute after login in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, configuration, struts2, dmi

I have the following usecase that on `Login` a `CustomerForm` should be shown and a `ListofCustomers` which is retrieved from Database should be shown.

I have written the following code in Struts 2 but my `getCustomerList()` in `CustomerAction` is not getting called which is redirected during the `Login` action in `struts.xml`

**`web.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Struts 2 Entry Point is Filter -->
<web-app id="WebApp_9" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Struts2 Application</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC     "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN" 
 "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts >
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="ApplicationResources" />
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="mylogging"
                class="com.rahul.interceptor.MyLoggingInterceptor">
            </interceptor>
            <interceptor-stack name="loggingStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="mylogging" />
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>
        <action name="login" class="com.rahul.action.LoginAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="loggingStack" />
            <result type="redirect">/customer?method=getCustomersList</result>
            <result name="success">Welcome.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">Login.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="customer" class="com.rahul.action.CustomerAction">
        
        <interceptor-ref name="loggingStack" />
            <result name="success">SuccessCustomer.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">Customer.jsp</result>
        </action>
        
    </package>
</struts>
```

**`login.jsp`:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Struts 2 - Login Application</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Struts 2 Login Application</h2>
    <s:actionerror />
    <s:form action="login" method="post">
        <s:textfield name="username" key="label.username" size="20" />
        <s:password name="password" key="label.password" size="20" />
        <s:submit method="execute" key="label.login" align="center" />
    </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**`loginAction.java`:**

```
package com.rahul.action;

public class LoginAction {
    private String userName;
    private String password;

    public String execute() {
        if (this.userName.equals("admin") && this.password.equals("admin123")) {
            return "success";
        } else {
            return "error";
        }
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.userName = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

**`CustomerAction.java`:**

```
package com.rahul.action;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class CustomerAction extends ActionSupport {
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private String email;
    private String telephone;
    private List<String> customerList;
    private String countryName;

    public String getCountryName() {
        
        System.out.println("getCountryName method");
        countryName="India";
        
        return countryName;
    }

    public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }

    public String addCustomer() {
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getTelephone() {
        return telephone;
    }

    public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }

    public List<String> getCustomerList() {
        return customerList;
    }

    public void setCustomerList(List<String> customerList) {
        this.customerList = customerList;
    }
    
    
    public String getCustomersList() {
        System.out.println("Inside Customer List");
        customerList = new ArrayList<String>();
        customerList.add("Rahul");
        customerList.add("Saurabh");
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

**`welcome.jsp`:**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>
        Howdy,
        <s:property value="username" />
        ...!
    </h2>
    <%@include file="Customer.jsp"%>
</body>
</html>
```

**`Customer.jsp`:**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Customer Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <s:form action="customer.action" method="post" validate="true">
        <s:textfield name="name" key="name" size="20" />
        <s:textfield name="age" key="age" size="20" />
        <s:textfield name="email" key="email" size="20" />
        <s:textfield name="telephone" key="telephone" size="20" />
        <s:submit method="addCustomer" key="label.add.customer" align="center" />

    </s:form>
<s:property value="customerList" />


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You did not accept the answer to your previous post and you are posting another one. Do you think it is easy to spend time answering one's question? How it is done here on stackoverflow.com is, if an answer solves your problem, you accept it by clicking on the grey tick icon.

Comment: @Uchenna Nwanyanwu It has not solved my problem thats why i thought to submit the code which i have written.

Comment: If it did not solve your issue, why did you change the title of the post to `Struts 2 Action redirect now working`. You should have updated your previous question with the code instead of creating a new one.

Comment: sorry for the typo it was not not now

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a `method` as parameter name. This name is reserved for special parameter used by [DMI](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-configuration.html#dynamic-method-invocation) and have a special syntax. First, if you want to use this parameter and DMI you should enable it.

```
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="true" />
```

then

```
<result type="redirect">/customer?method:getCustomersList</result>
```

Note, use a colon to specify a method name in parameter.

or use equivalent syntax

```
<result type="redirect">/customer!getCustomersList</result>
```

You might also wonder: [Is a colon safe for friendly-URL use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2053132/573032)

Also, don't use `.action` extension in the struts tags

```
<s:form namespace="/" action="customer" method="post" validate="true">
    <s:textfield name="name" key="name" size="20" />
    <s:textfield name="age" key="age" size="20" />
    <s:textfield name="email" key="email" size="20" />
    <s:textfield name="telephone" key="telephone" size="20" />
    <s:submit method="addCustomer" key="label.add.customer" align="center" />
</s:form>
```

Note, the method attribute used by the struts tag to add a special parameter to the form url: `method:addCustomer`. This parameter only works with DMI. If you used namespace to the action configuration you should use it in the `form` tag as well.