# Can URL contain colons to represent a value other than port number

Tags: http

Can URL contain colons to represent a value other than port number. The value can be a mac address of a machine.

## Sample URL

`http://172.17.48.10/lab/first/C0:4A:00:40:71:0A/wan`

Comment: What is the intended use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053132/is-a-colon-safe-for-friendly-url-use might be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're referring to is an *HTTP* URL. There are dozens of other URL types out there -- after all, URL stands for nothing more than *uniform ressource locator*, ie. is an instruction on how to find a specific ressource.

Many URL types share the form of HTTP URLs (eg. FTP, HTTPS etc), which is

```
{protocol}://{hostname}[:port][/path]
```

where `path` can be quite everything, including things with colons; normally you'd see these being URL-encoded (the stuff with `%` in URLs). Why don't you simply try out; the full syntax is documented in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).

Comment: @Muller thanks. Yes I referred the rfc 3986. The colon is part of Reserved Characters. My doubt was the colons which are part of "/path" must be percent-encoded or it can allow those.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: yes. And as Marcus said: the specs are out there.