# Colon : in a REST WCF Request

Tags: rest, wcf

So I have a URL to my wcf service that looks like this:

`http://dev.verse-master.com/api/VerseMasterService.svc/Search/bi/isaiah 34:16/0/60`

My operation contract looks like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Search/{translation}/{searchTerm}/{skip}/{take}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
VerseMaster.BusinessLayer.DataObjects.ServerObjects.GetVersesSearchServerObject GetVersesBySearch(string translation, string searchTerm, string skip, string take);
```

I have tried from reading online to add this line to the web.config:

```
<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="4.0"/>
```

But I still get this error:

> HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe related (though apparently not duplicate) [Using a colon (:) in a url with ASP.NET/IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/667429/3744182).

Answer (score 0):

encode the url and it should be fine, just handle it when it returns. that'll help with the backslash as well which will cause equal amounts of problems as the :

eg

calling the service:

```
String encodedSearchTerm = Server.UrlEncode(searchTerm);
String UrlToCall = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}","http://dev.verse-master.com/api/VerseMasterService.svc/Search/bi/",encodedSearchTerm,"/0/60");
```

...etc...

then in your operation:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Search/{translation}/{searchTerm}/{skip}/{take}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)] 
VerseMaster.BusinessLayer.DataObjects.ServerObjects.GetVersesSearchServerObject GetVersesBySearch(string translation, string searchTerm, string skip, string take){
...etc...
String DecodedSearchTerm= Server.UrlDecode(searchTerm);
...etc...
}
```

rememeber need to import `System.Web`

Comment: Of course I could do that, but how can I run the wcf service and ALLOW colons