# WCF rejecting request with "400 Bad Request" when their is a colon in the URL data

Tags: c#, wcf, urlencode, url-encoding, self-hosting

I'm trying something pretty simple using a *self hosted WCF service*, and I can't believe I've spent half a day just trying to get this to work.

I've got a UriTemplate for the following endpoint.

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate="{documentName}?catalog={catalog}")]
DocData FindJobInfo(string documentName, string catalog);
```

And it rejects requests to it with a "400 Bad Request" error when I try to hit it with a URL that has colons in the **docuementName** parameter. An actual example follows:

```
http://localhost:59982/dms/:Q9:m:w:x:h:~140410145342551.nev?catalog=test
```

For those of you who are about to say "UrlEncode it".  It also fails with this request:

```
http://localhost:59982/dms/%3AQ9%3Am%3Aw%3Ax%3Ah%3A~140410145342551.nev?catalog=test
```

*However*... if i replace all the colons with semi colons in the **documentName**... it works:

```
http://localhost:59982/dms/;Q9;m;w;x;h;~140410145342551.nev?catalog=test
```

What in the world?  Also, the first URL format should work just fine because I can hit a vendors site using that same **documentName** with colons and all and it works fine.  I've even tried adding the following to the web.config and it still doesn't work:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
```

---

**EDIT**

I've had a response claiming that colons simply aren't valid in the URL, yet I hit vendor endpoints with them just fine.  Here is an example:

```
https://api.site.company.com/v1/Document/:Q9:m:w:x:h:~140410145342551.nev/info
```

This is an exact REST call with the company name changed for privacy.  I have no problems retrieving data from this endpoint.  I don't see why they would choose such a crazy looking ID to address their resources.  But they did, and it works for them.  Why can't I get my endpoints to accept them.

Comment: Presumably those vendor endpoints are not WCF REST services so the fact they work is not relevant to your problem anyway. Have you looked at the documentation/source code for [UriTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uritemplate(v=vs.110).aspx)? I believe the support for URLs they provide is quite limited

Comment: As you are self hosting I believe the <system.web> section in your config will be ignored

Comment: @Schneider I very much doubt the vendor is using WCF to host their product API.  Also, what makes you think that <system.web> is ignored when self hosting?  This might explain a few things, but where have you seen this at before?

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of system.webServer

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by ASP.NET/IIS settings. As standard, the following characters are not allowed in the URL for some security and mechanism reasons:

- <
- >
- *
- %
- :
- &
- \

You can either allow all characters, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5783607/2132796), or just remove the colon character, like this:

```
requestPathInvalidCharacters="<,>,*,%,&,\"
```

You can read furhter information and the **risks about this** behavior in [this article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx) by Scott Hanselman on his blog.

Comment: I mentioned right in my problem statement that I already tried this.  I even provided that XML I used in my .config file. Not sure how you missed that, but this did not work for me.  I should mention however that I'm using a self hosted WCF service and NOT IIS.  Not sure if that matters, but I'll add this info to the problem description.